# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' - TKINTER

Tags: tkinter

Ya se que esta pregunta tiene varias respuesta, pero esas respuestas no he podido conseguir solucionar este error.

**Contexto**:

Tengo una APP, que me añade ventanas en un Notebook, desde un boton, la ventana que añade tiene 2 frames, uno para el MENU y otro un TXT.

Cuando presiono el evento **Control-l**, me oculta y vuelvo a presionar me lo muestra, hasta hay funciona perfecto, pero si yo presiono **Control-f**, me habre un Toplevel, como simulando un buscador, aqui es el problema que si yo vuelvo a darle **Control-l**, para mostrar y oculta me da este error :

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/esy9f47u/Alvaro/Desarrollo/APPCompliance/showHide.py", line 13, in <lambda>
    self.bind_all('<Control-l>', lambda e : self.close_frame(e))
  File "/home/esy9f47u/Alvaro/Desarrollo/APPCompliance/showHide.py", line 26, in close_frame
    self.create_frame()
  File "/home/esy9f47u/Alvaro/Desarrollo/APPCompliance/showHide.py", line 31, in create_frame
    self.frame = tk.Frame(self, background="#F4F4F4")
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2744, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2292, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2281, in _setup
    self._w = master._w + '.' + name
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

, esto es una version de mi codigo real asi que esta todo simple.

**APP.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from showHide import Extracion
from tkinter import ttk
class Aplicacion():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.root =  tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Show and Hide")
        self.root.geometry('1024x768')

        self.cuaderno = ttk.Notebook(self.root)
        self.contenedor = tk.Frame(self.cuaderno, bg='silver')

        self.cuaderno.add(self.contenedor, text="Workspace")
        self.cuaderno.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.btn = tk.Button(self.contenedor, 
            text="ADD EXTRACION", 
            bg='gold',
            command=self.añadir
            )
        self.btn.pack()
    
    def añadir(self):
        extracion = Extracion(self.cuaderno, app)
        self.cuaderno.add(extracion, text='Extracion')
    
    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Aplicacion()
    app.mainloop()
```

**showHide.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext as st
from tkinter import ttk

on = 1
_estado_actual = False

class Extracion(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, app, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.app = app
        self.create_frame()
        self.bind_all('<Control-l>', lambda e : self.close_frame(e))
        self.bind_all('<Control-f>', lambda e : self.searchPanel(e))


    def close_frame(self, event):
        global on
        if on:
            self.frame1.pack_forget()
            on = 0
        else:
            self.frame.pack_forget()
            self.frame1.pack_forget()
            self.frame2.pack_forget()
            self.create_frame()
            
            on = 1

    def create_frame(self):
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self, background="#F4F4F4")
        self.frame.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH)
        
        self.frame2 = tk.Frame(self.frame)
        self.frame2.pack(side="right", expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
        
        self.txt = st.ScrolledText(
                self.frame2,
                font=("Helvetica", 12),
            )
        self.txt.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self.frame, background='cyan')
        self.frame1.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH)
        
        self.btn_close = tk.Button(
            self.frame1,
            background="gold",
            text="Hide"
        )
        self.btn_close.pack(expand=0, anchor='ne')
        
        self.treeview = ttk.Treeview(
            self.frame1,
        )
        self.treeview.heading("#0", text="FICHEROS de EXTRACIONES", anchor="center")
        self.treeview.pack(fill='both', expand=True, ipadx=50)
        
        self.max = tk.Button(
            self.frame1,
            width=4,
            text="+",
            background="gold"
        )
        self.max.pack(side="right", expand=0)

        self.min = tk.Button(
            self.frame1,
            width=4,
            text="-",
            background="gold"
        )
        self.min.pack(side="left", expand=0)

    def searchPanel(self, event=None):
        global _estado_actual
        if not _estado_actual:
            self.busca_top = tk.Toplevel(self.frame1)
            self._w = 0
            self._y = 0
            window_width = 680
            window_height = 100
            bus_reem_top_msg_w = 240
            self.busca_top.overrideredirect(True)
            screen_width = (self.app.root.winfo_x() + 640)
            screen_height = (self.app.root.winfo_y()+40)
            position_top = int(screen_height)
            position_right = int(screen_width)
            self.busca_top.geometry(
                f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{position_right}+{position_top}')
            
            self.busca_top.config(
                bg="cyan", 
                padx=5, 
                pady=5
            )

            self.busca_frm_tit = tk.Frame(
                self.busca_top,
            )
            self.busca_frm_tit.pack(fill='x', expand=1)

            self.busca_frm_content = tk.Frame(
                self.busca_top,
                bg="silver",
                padx=5,
                pady=10
            )
            self.busca_frm_content.pack(fill='x', expand=1)

            self.busca_top.title('Buscar')
            self.bus_reem_num_results = tk.StringVar()
            self.bus_reem_num_results.set('~ {} ~'.format('No hay resultados'))

            self.buscar_01_msg = tk.Message(
                self.busca_frm_tit,
                textvariable=self.bus_reem_num_results,
                padx=10,
                pady=0
            )
            self.buscar_01_msg.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
            self.buscar_01_msg.config(
                width=bus_reem_top_msg_w,
                foreground="black",
                justify='center',
                font=("Helvetica", 14, 'bold')
            )

            self.var_entry_bsc = tk.StringVar(self)
            
            self.entr_str = tk.Entry(
                self.busca_frm_content,
                textvariable=self.var_entry_bsc,
            )
            self.entr_str.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, sticky="nsew")

            self.btn_cerrar_buscar = tk.Button(
                self.busca_frm_content,
                text='X',
            )
            self.btn_cerrar_buscar.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)

            self.btn_limpiar = tk.Button(
                self.busca_frm_content,
                text='<<',
            )

            self.btn_limpiar.grid(
                row=0, column=1, padx=(5, 0), pady=5, sticky="nsew")

            self.btn_buscar_prev = tk.Button(
                self.busca_frm_content,
                text='<|',
            )

            self.btn_buscar_prev.grid(
                row=0, column=2, padx=(5, 0), pady=5, sticky="nsew")

            self.btn_buscar_next = tk.Button(
                self.busca_frm_content,
                text='|>',
            )

            self.btn_buscar_next.grid(
                row=0, column=3, padx=(5, 0), pady=5, sticky="nsew")

            self.entr_str.focus_set()

            _estado_actual = True
        else:
            _estado_actual = True
            return 'break'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explicación

El problema proviene de esta linea:

```
self._w = 0
```

El atributo `_w` tiene un uso interno dentro de Tkinter: es una referencia a un string que representa al widget. Recuerda que Python no tiene atributos privados, por lo que puedes cambiar el valor que contiene dicho atributo sin ningún problema.

Esto complica internamente a Tkinter, ya que sigue asumiendo que `_w` sigue representando al widget. El error es más bien interno: pues intenta concatenar un número con una cadena y eso no es posible.

#### Solución

Simplemente cambia el nombre del atributo a otro que no use Tkinter internamente. Ejemplo: `_x`

Comment: Ok si tienes razón, porque esa variable la uso en otra parte del código, no creia que me estuviera afectando, que buen ojo tienes Dante, como el error no me da en esa línea no se me cruzo por la mente que fuera justo hay.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada Lopuma c: